# Using Re.split to construct dictionary from file

Tags: python

im reading a file and this line in the file is giving me problems. it is

```
CSE 3380,professional,CSE 2315,note: MATH 3330 can be taken instead
```

the code i wrote to split this was using the re.split module to follow the pattern that these type of files will follow which is

```
class(comma) catagory(comma) prereq class(comma) note(semicolon)
```

theres multiple lines that are all built the same way but some have dashes and other characters so a method that splits based of non alphabetical characters wont help. i want to split at the comma, comma, comma, semicolon thingy

```
course, catagory, pre, note = re.split(', |, |, |: ', line)
```

I get an error saying "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack". Im not sure why. i used this method in other different pattern lines but for this particular pattern im having trouble.

Comment: you can print re.split(', |, |, |: ', line) to see what return, then compare what you need.

Comment: yea i print it but i get that error up there

Comment: This online tester is helpful - http://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 2):

Just split by semicolon first, and then split the first part using a comma:

```
>>> var = 'CSE 3380,professional,CSE 2315,note: MATH 3330 can be taken instead'
>>> var = var.split(':')
>>> var
['CSE 3380,professional,CSE 2315,note', ' MATH 3330 can be taken instead']
>>> var[0] = var[0].split(',')
>>> var
[['CSE 3380', 'professional', 'CSE 2315', 'note'], ' MATH 3330 can be taken instead']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
line = "CSE 3380,professional,CSE 2315,note: MATH 3330 can be taken instead"
parts = re.match('^(.*?), ?(.*?), ?(.*?)(?:, ?note: ?(.*))$', line).groups()
```

Then `parts` is the tuple:

```
('CSE 3380', 'professional', 'CSE 2315', 'MATH 3330 can be taken instead')
```

Or to get it as an easier to use dictionary:

```
line = "CSE 3380,professional,CSE 2315,note: MATH 3330 can be taken instead"
parts = re.match('^(?P<class>.*?), ?(?P<catagory>.*?), ?(?P<prereq>.*?)(?:, ?note: ?(?P<note>.*))$', line).groupdict()
```

Which sets `parts` to:

```
{'note': 'MATH 3330 can be taken instead', 'prereq': 'CSE 2315', 'catagory': 'professional', 'class': 'CSE 3380'}
```